# How to get device token for iOs and regisration ID for andorid for push notification?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am using pushSharp library. I see deviceToken in sample code 
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp
Can anybody help me how to get that ? pushSharp sample code doesn't explain that

```
apnsBroker.QueueNotification (new ApnsNotification {
        DeviceToken = deviceToken,
        Payload = JObject.Parse ("{\"aps\":{\"badge\":7}}")
```

Same for Android, How to get Resistation ID's

```
foreach (var regId in MY_REGISTRATION_IDS) {
    // Queue a notification to send
    gcmBroker.QueueNotification (new GcmNotification {
        RegistrationIds = new List<string> { 
            regId
        },
        Data = JObject.Parse ("{ \"somekey\" : \"somevalue\" }")
    });
}
```

I am sending push notification via my service layer which is developed in C#.